# Which method is better to initialize a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Please tell me which method would be better in this case, I want to use std::find later for the vectors.
Vectors will include all times a tiny dataset.
Thank you.

```
int main()
{   
    // method1
    std::vector<int> v1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
    bool cond;
    if (cond)
    {
        // find something in v1
    }
    else
    {
        v1 = {1,2,3};
        // find something in v1 with new values
    }
    
    // method2
    std::vector<int> v1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
    bool cond;
    if (cond)
    {
        // find something in v1
    }
    else
    {
        std::vector<int> v2 = {1,2,3};
        // find something in v2
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: whats wrong with the way you do initialize the vectors? Btw I dont understand the difference between 1 and 2. in 1 you use 1 vector while in 2 you are using 2 vectors. Whether you need 1 or 2 vectors only you can know.

Comment: nothing wrong, I just want to know which method is preferable.

Comment: if second brannch is entered I don't need anymore the first vector

Comment: do you want to assign new elements to `v1` or do you want to create a new vector `v2`. Thats orthogonal to how you initialize them, and depends on what you actually need

Comment: method 3: make a separate function that returns the vector based on the condition, no uninitialised or reassigned or duplicated vectors needed. but I guess this is too opinion-based really, without a clear problem statement and definition of what "better" means.

Comment: I am afraid the example is too much stripped down to demonstrate your real issue. Why search an element in a vector when you just initialized it with known elements?

Comment: Define "better". What are you measuring?

Comment: "if second brannch is entered I don't need anymore the first vector" then why is `v1` not declared within the first `if` case?

Comment: the method will get a value which I need to see if is in one set of elemnts (v1), if not I need to check if is in another set of elements (v1 with new values or create a new v2 ?)

Comment: Readability-wise having a new variable is the best thing. Obviously if `v1` is large then you might not be able to afford that.

Comment: I admit I didn't describe really well the issue, so in cond I check values from vector..

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the vector? If so, use method 1, if not method 2 to create a new vector.

Comment: That's what I'm not sure about, whether it's better to overwrite the vector or to create a new one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second 'else' block is entered, do you need the values in v1? If not, you can simply re-use the memory capacity in v1 rather than constructing a new vector 'v2' within the scope of a conditional block (you seem to want to discard the contents of v1 anyway)

```
v1 = {1,2,3}
```

This line re-uses the memory already allocated by v1 and simply copies over values from '{1,2,3}'

From: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/:
(your example falls under case 3)

> Any elements held in the container before the call are either assigned to or destroyed.